# Removing Ubuntu to install Arch Linux dual booting with pre installed Windows 8

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have a dual boot Windows 8 + Linux Ubuntu right now which boots through GRUB. I want to remove the Ubuntu though & install Arch Linux. I made a bootable flash drive of Arch & almost deleted the current Ubuntu partition when I realized my GRUB would also go, making it hard to boot into Windows.

How would you suggest I proceed?

NOTE: I am on a Legacy (BIOS-MBR boot mode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to “uninstall” an operating system. Simply replace it with the new one. Launch the Arch Linux installer and select to overwrite the Ubuntu partition. Arch’s GRUB should detect Windows just like Ubuntu does.

Comment: Sweet, I was worried if Arch's GRUB would replace the previous configuration.